# How to Pass vararg to a varag function or constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin does not allow my subclass to pass vararg to my super class constuctor
Here is my Operation class:

```
package br.com.xp.operation

import java.util.ArrayList

abstract class Operation(vararg values: Value) : Value {
    protected var values: MutableList<Value> = ArrayList()

    internal abstract val operator: String
}
```

and here is my SubtractionOperation class:

```
package br.com.xp.operation

class SubtractionOperation private constructor(vararg values: Value) : Operation(values) {
    override val operator: String
        get() = "-"
}
```

The compile says:

> Type mismatch Required Value found Array

Can anyone explain why this is not possible?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> Inside a function a `vararg`-parameter of type `T` is visible as an array of `T`.

So in the `SubtractionOperation` constructor, `values` is really an `Array<Value>`.  You need to use the **spread** operator (`*`) to forward these on:

```
class SubtractionOperation private constructor(vararg values: Value) : Operation(*values) ...
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that (IIRC) this creates a new array.

Comment: I believe https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20462 fixes this performance/memory allocation issue. 1.2-Beta2 contains this fix.

Comment: This works. I now wonder how you would do this on Java. Does anyone know?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - I don't think you need to do anything special in Java.  This just works: `void a(String... strings) { /* Stuff */ } void b(String... strings) { a(strings); }`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth OK thanks. I was sure it didn't work for me at some point, as this is actually what I've tried, but now on POC it does work, so something else must have caused the initial error.