# Listen into a method call of a class I don't own

Tags: java, kotlin

Explanation of the problem.

I am using a library that is essentially a web server. This web server has a user login manager class and in that class there is a `onUserLogin(User user)` method that is triggered every time a user is logged in. I do not have access to the source code and I don't want to change it even if I had.

I want to know if it is possible to somehow register an event that is triggered every time this method is called and get the argument that it was called with on my code.

For more context, my code is a library that this webserver will use in return but the only thing that the webserver is blindly registering all plugins from a single entry point without offering any other API.

Comment: Did you already read this question about intercepting method calls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372165/intercepting-method-calls

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is that I am using Kotlin. The reason why I added the java tag was just in case there is a java solution that can be used in Kotlin too.

Comment: Can you use a proxy similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52082041/3755692

Comment: @msrd0 don't proxies require to be called as proxies in the first place? I don't have access to the code that is calling the `onUserLogin`.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but I wouldn't be supprised if that was some java reflection magic that you could use to intercept that call - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: Could you elaborate on what webserver do you use?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin It doesn't matter. It's not even a webserver, its a private emulator's loginserver, but I wanted to make the issue relatable to what most people know. It doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: It does matter, actually. If you control how this "server" is started, you could use instrumentation to change the class, as described here: http://armoredbarista.blogspot.com/2012/01/patching-java-at-runtime.html . I could produce you an example, if you're really interested.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin No it doesn't. I am not looking for runtime patching but rather compile time or runtime interception interception. I don't wanna change the class. I wanna add "after" behaviour.